# How to create an object graph from an array

Tags: java

i have an array with some data and need to create an object graph. Im not sure how to itterate through the array and create/link the objects.
here is examle:

```
Array
a1 b1 c1
a1 b1 c2
a1 b2 c3
```

At the end I should have an object A with id a1 which contains a list of two objects B (with id b1 and b2) and those contains 3 Objects C (b1 contains list of c1 and c2 and b2 contains c3)

```
example for the classes:
class A{
string id;
List<B> bs;
}
class B{
Sting id;
List<C> cs;
}
class C{
String id;
}
```

Comment: you are talking about writing a parser

Comment: why parser? from the array i know that each column represents a specific object (column 1 = A, column 2 = B...). So at the end i need a HashMap where I store the information about the id's. If id a1 is not in the hashMap -> create new object A and so on. My problem is, Im not sure hot to iterate and link objects

Comment: ControlAltDel it isn't the parsing he's struggling with so much as how to build up the relationships after parsing. Its a fair question.

Answer (score 0):

Create some POJO class or tuple to hold the values.

Split the string based on the separator (space)

Loop through the string token array and insert values into objects and create relationships between them based on the names.

If there only ever 3 elements you can hard-code it and it'll be easy. If there's a variable number then you need to be smarter and have an array or set of POJOs/nodes so you can retrieve one based on the name.

Here's some pseudocode to help

```
String[] tokens = str.split(' ');
Set<node> nodes = new HashMap<String, node>();
while(has more tokens in tokens){
String s = tokens.next();
if(nodes.get(s) == null){
Node n = new node();
nodes.add(s, n);
}
else{
Node n = nodes.get(s);
}
n.name = s;
String s2 = tokens.next();
Node n2 = nodes.get(  s2 ); // retrieve node based on name
if(n2 == null){
    Node n2 = new node();
    n2.name = s2;
    nodes.add(s2, n2);
}
n.left = n2;
// do same thing for the other child
```

You can do it with arrays or sets or however you wish.

E: Do not create 3 classes. That's bad. There's no reason the 3 objects shouldn't have the same class. You want a universal generic node class that can fill all of their purpose so its nice an OOP to navigate the tree of nodes. Getting different class types A, B, C from each other is bad and will make working with the objects very painful in the code.

What you want is a single "Node" class, and then 3 different instances of it.

Node a, Node b, Node c;

That way they can all link to each other generically.

```
Class Node

Node left;
Node right;

Public Node(){}
```

That's all there is to it. You can encapsulate the left and right nodes with get/set methods if you wish.

(Ignore this if for some crazy reason you have an assignment that tells you to use A, B and C classes)